# Calculus: Maximum and Minimum Values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

After the consumption of an alcoholic beverage, the concentration of alcohol in the bloodstream (blood alcohol concentration, or BAC) surges as the alcohol is absorbed, followed by a gradual decline as the alcohol is metabolized. The function
$$C(t) = 1.35te^{−2.802t}$$

models the average BAC, measured in mg/mL, of a group of eight male subjects t hours after rapid consumption of $15 mL$ of ethanol (corresponding to one alcoholic drink).

What is the maximum average BAC during the first 6 hours?

When does it occur?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.35te%5E%28%E2%88%922.802t%29+for+t+%3D+0..5

Comment: also lol@"rapid consumption of 15mL of ethanol"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this pan out for $150$ mL?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this problem as follows because the product rule is messy.

First, hide the constants because it's just going to waste time writing:

$$f(t) = \alpha t e^{-\beta t}$$

Let's rewrite this in a convenient form:

$$f(t) = \alpha e^{\ln t} e^{-\beta t} = \alpha e^{\ln t - \beta t}$$

Since $e^x$ is strictly increasing (make sure you understand what I mean here, at least intuitively), it will be maximized exactly when its argument is maximized, so we can maximize instead:

$$g(t) = \ln t - \beta t$$

This has the simple first order condition:

$$g'(t) = \frac{1}{t} - \beta = 0$$

Which clearly has solution $t^{*} = \frac{1}{\beta}$. Going back to the problem formulation we see $\beta = 2.802$.

Technically to be sure it's maximized we need to check the second order condition, and that of $g$ will suffice (again, check your understanding of why this is true, intuitively and/or through math):

$$g''(t^{*}) = -\frac{1}{(t^{*})^2}<0$$

And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the derivative of $C(t)$:

$$C'(t)=1.35t\cdot(-2.802)e^{-2.802t}+1.35e^{-2.802t}$$

It has an optimum $t_{0}$ if $C'(t_{0})=0$ and $C''(t_{0})\neq 0$. Here, we have $$\begin{align}
C'(t_{0}) &=0\\
1.35t_{0}\cdot(-2.802)e^{-2.802t_{0}}+1.35e^{-2.802t_{0}}&=0\\
e^{-2.802t_{0}}\left(-1.35\cdot 2.802t_{0}+1.35 \right) &=0
\end{align}$$
It is clear that $e^{-2.802t_{0}}\neq 0$ for all $t_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$, so that 
$$-1.35\cdot 2.802t_{0}+1.35=0$$
and you get
$$t_{0}=\frac{1}{2.802}\approx0.36$$

I assume $t$ is in hours, so that it makes $t_{0}=0.36\,\text{h}\approx 21.41\min$. This is the only optimum and one should verify it is indeed a maximum, i.e. $C''(t_{0})<0$.

You can easily compute the maximum average BAC, which is $C(t_{0})=C\left(2.802^{-1}\right)$. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%201.35te%5E%28%E2%88%922.802t%29%20for%20t%3D0%20to%206) can be an useful tool to check your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just as MichaelChirico suggested to do, you want to maximize $$f = \alpha\, t \,e^{-\beta t}$$ That is to say to find the zero of its derivative $f'$.

When you have this kind of expressions, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier. $$\log(f)=\log(\alpha)+\log(t)-\beta t$$ Differentiation both sides $$\frac {f'}f=\frac 1t-\beta$$ and, since $f'=0$, then $\frac {f'}f=0$ and finally $t=\frac 1 \beta$.